# Directly authenticate(login) after successful signup in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

How can i directly authenticate the user after signup.
Below are the the deatail of serializeUser and deserializeUser.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, {tutorId: user.tutorId, userType: user.userType});
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(userData, done) {
  Tutor.getTutorById(userData.tutorId, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      try {
        logger.silly(`message: POST inside passport.deserializeUser; file: index.js; error: ${err}; user: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`);
        logger.error(`message: POST inside passport.deserializeUser; file: index.js; error: ${err}; user: ${JSON.stringify(user)}`);
      } catch (e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `req.login()` after successful registration.

From official Passport documentation:

> Note: `passport.authenticate()` middleware invokes `req.login()`
>   automatically. This function is primarily used when users sign up,
>   during which `req.login()` can be invoked to automatically log in the
>   newly registered user.

A sample registration code might look like this:

```
router.post("/register",(req,res) => {
    var user = new User();
    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    //define other things here
    //create hash and salt here
    user.save().then(user => {
        //on successfult registration
        //login user here, using req.login
        req.login(user ,err => {
            if(!err){
                //redirect to logged-in page
                //or user page
                res.redirect('/')
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Read about [req.login() in official passport documentsation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/)

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

you can create token just after successful registration and send it back in registration response